# SQL update to NULL using a variable

Tags: php, sql, null

I keep having problems with quotes in relation to a table update. I'm sending a Post with several values from a form, and then update a table with them. For the code to work, I need to wrap keys with backslash (`$ColumnaString`), and values with single quotes (`$ValueString`). This works OK. My problem is that occasionally I want to update to NULL (when `$value==""`). But my present code don't do that. Can somebody spot the problem?

```
$id_tag=trim($_POST['id']);
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if ($key!="UpdatePeople"){
        $ColumnaString="`".$key."`";
        $ValueString="'".iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT', utf8_encode($value))."'";
        if ($key=="In_Date" and $value=="") {$ValueString==NULL;} //Hereis my problem I think
        $link->query("UPDATE MyTable SET ".$ColumnaString."=".$ValueString." WHERE `id`=".$id_tag."");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check $id_tag and create a proper part of sql code

```
$str = ($id_tag ='' ) ? ' is null ' : ' = '.$id_tag;

$link->query("UPDATE MyTable SET ".$ColumnaString." = ".$ValueString." WHERE `id`".str."");
```

and for  $vale

```
if ($key=="In_Date" and $value=="") { $ValueString = 'NULL' ;} //Hereis my problem I think
```

Comment: Tried it with no results. In order to understand your suggestion: you are asking if `$id_tag` is empty, in that case you set the variable `$str` to `is nul`, else concatenate `=` and the value of `$id_tag`, right? If it is this way, I think I should apply something like that to the value associated with `$key=="In_Date"`.

Comment: Thats it! Single quotes, double quotes, backquotes are going to drive me crazy...  Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

check your database if the columns is defined as NOT NULL

Comment: DB is ok. Nulls allowed (actually, is full of nulls right now).